# Drow Noble: possibilities to not be seen by them (if one has a magic item/spell active)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

As [Drow Nobles](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/drow-common/drow-noble) have *detect magic* as a constant, what can evade their sight?

I'm unsure about these 2 normal situations:

- a) A person who has some magic item trying to sneak up on the Drow
- b) An item in a wooden chest

---

a) If the person tries to use Stealth, there is a huge problem. The Drow sees the aura of the person's items, which stands out if there is no other (stronger) aura in the area, and there is not thick stone wall between them. Am I right that in this case, the person can't sneak up on or hide from the Drow? (Invisibility does not work, as stated in other questions, as invisibility can be broken by *detect magic*. Thus  at the latest, on the third turn the Drow would be able to target the person.)

b) *Detect magic* can see through the chest. That means that without "magic aura", or the magic item being divine in nature, the Drow can see the aura, and latest at the third turn determine what form the item has. Is there any possibility to avoid this without having to resort to those 2 things?

On b) Similar: Is there any way, aside from magic aura, to hide a magical trap from a Drow Noble?

Answer (score 3):

It's not "magic sight", it's a *detect magic* spell with infinite duration. You still have to follow the rules of the spell before you can see magic auras.

In case (a) constant-duration *detect magic* only reveals magic auras *after* you study an area for at least a round, so it doesn't let you automatically notice someone sneaking up while carrying a magic item.

In case of (b), you can see the aura through the chest, but even three turns of inspection won't reveal anything other than strength or location, as the rest of the information requires line of sight, or knowing that it's a magic item (which you can't determine just from the strength and location information).

Comment: so for a.) it would be so that if you try to walk at him with a invisibility spell he would see you (if you dont sneak just walk up)  but if you use stealth he would still need a perception spell?

b.) isnt he also able to discern also the form of the item from the aura? or is the aura a bit more diffuse?

Comment: or do you mean that the drow would have to study the area in front of him for one turn and then he would see the guy who is trying to sneak from shadow to shadow in his direction (coming from the direction the drow looks at) / seeing the guy hiding in a shallow alcove in that direction ?

Comment: It works *exactly* the same as a normal detect magic spell. The only change is duration (it doesn't end), but otherwise is identical.

Answer (score 0):

The [nondetection](http://paizo.com/prd/spells/nondetection.html) spell is the most direct way to prevent this:

> The warded creature or object becomes difficult to detect by divination spells such as clairaudience/clairvoyance, locate object, and detect spells. Nondetection also prevents location by such magic items as crystal balls. If a divination is attempted against the warded creature or item, the caster of the divination must succeed on a caster level check (1d20 + caster level) against a DC of 11 + the caster level of the spellcaster who cast nondetection. If you cast nondetection on yourself or on an item currently in your possession, the DC is 15 + your caster level.

Of particular importance is the note:

> If cast on a creature, nondetection wards the creature's gear as well as the creature itself.

This means a spellcaster who can cast *nondetection* (a level 3 Sor/Wiz spell) can hide himself *and his gear* for at least 5 hours with a single spell. It would still be possible to detect him with an appropriate caster level check. An [Amulet of Proof Against Detection and Location](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-proof-against-detection-and-location) spell would be a permanent (if a bit expensive) version.

Someone hiding a magic object in a chest, or laying a magical trap, could similarly cast *nondetection* on it. A non-magical alternative would be to line the chest with lead, which blocks *detect* spells.